# Vue 3 Vuetify 3 v-data-table cells are not editable

Tags: vuejs3, vuetifyjs3, v-data-table

Since the upgrade from Vue 2 to Vue 3 and Vuetify 3, our datatable row cells are no longer editable. I have changed headers from using text,value to use title,key, and the rows are showing properly, they are just not editable. Have searched and can't find for latest version of vue/vuetify.

Here is the code (cannot show picture of resultant table). Appreciate any assistance, there is something I am missing with latest version. Note: We had v-slot:body before we upgraded, but if I use that now, my rows won't even show, so I switched it to pageText, and at least my rows now show, the cells are just not editable.

```
      <v-data-table :headers="computedHeaders" :items="computedItems">
        <template v-slot:pageText="{ items, headers }">
          <tbody>
            <tr v-for="(item, idx) in items" :key="idx">
              <td v-for="(header, indx) in headers" :key="indx" :class="'text-' + header.align">
                <v-edit-dialog :return-value.sync="item[header.key]" large>
                  {{ item[header.key] }}
                  <template v-slot:input>
                    <v-text-field v-model="item[header.key]" label="Edit" single-line></v-text-field>
                  </template>
                </v-edit-dialog>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </template>
      </v-data-table>
```

Comment: You have a lot of code that may not be relevant to the problem. Try recreating your table step by step and see where it breaks. Try to give us a playground maybe showcasing the problem. You should give a bit more effort for your question imo

Comment: You are correct, and I apologize for that. I have focused the code area in which I have whittled down the problem yesterday.  The problem area is here: <template v-slot:pageText="{ items, headers }". If I put that back to <template v-slot:body="{ items, headers }"> as we had in Vue 2, the rows of data will not show. Found pageText and changed to that, which now allows my data rows to show; however, when hover over row, none of the cells are editable.  Spent hours on it yesterday. I feel I am missing a change to Vue3 or Vuetify3 that I am not instituting here. I will keep looking.

Comment: No need to apologize! Still giving us a working example even with one dummy row and some dummy headers would help us. Are you sure there is a v-edit-dialog component in vuetify 3?

Comment: Right on the spot. There is no v-edit-dialog in v3 evidently. Searching for replacement!

Comment: I think I'm going to need to use v-slot:activator in some way with v-dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well guys, here is how to make it work in vue3 and vuetify3. I still need to tweak the dialog to have save and cancel buttons, but all is working now:

```
      <v-data-table :headers="computedHeaders" :items="computedItems">
          <tbody>
            <tr v-for="(item, idx) in computedItems" :key="idx">
              <td v-for="(header, indx) in computedHeaders" :key="indx" :class="'text-' + header.align">
                
                 <v-dialog width="500">
                  <template v-slot:activator="{ props }">
                    <v-label v-bind="props">{{ item[header.key] }}</v-label>
                  </template>

                  <template v-slot:default="{ isActive }">
                    <v-card title="Dialog">
                      <v-card-text>
                        <v-text-field v-model="item[header.key]" label="Edit" single-line></v-text-field>
                      </v-card-text>

                      <v-card-actions>
                        <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                        <v-btn text="Close Dialog" @click="isActive.value = false"></v-btn>
                      </v-card-actions>
                    </v-card>
                  </template>
                </v-dialog>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
       </v-data-table>
```